# WPF TextBox in DataTemplate of ToggleButton does not show text if in toolbar flyout

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core, data-binding

If I put the Column where the toolbar is hosted to be very big (800) then all the text is visible:

[image: design time and run very big]

but if I put a smaller column this happens:

[image: not text shown]

But I cannot understand why:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IconFilterButton">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{StaticResource LargeIconStyle}"
                Text="{Binding}" />
            <TextBlock
                Margin="6,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                DataContext="{Binding}"
                Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"
                Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToggleButton}, Path=Tag}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and here the definition

```
            <ToggleButton
                x:Name="DFilter"
                Click="Filtering_Click"
                Content="&#xE161;"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconFilterButton}"
                Tag="1d" 
                />
            <ToggleButton
                x:Name="WFilter"
                Click="Filtering_Click"
                Content="&#xE8C0;"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconFilterButton}"
                Tag="1w" 
                />
```

Even worst if I click on the button once they are out:

[image: clicked item]

and then the text is visible but is wrong as the TextBlock is not considered in the object size:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The WPF `ToolBar` control uses a custom panel for the overflow `Popup`. In many styles, the `ToolBarOverFlowPanel` has a property `WrapWidth` set to a static value like `200`. This determines how many items can be displayed before it wraps to another row in the popup.

I've created custom styling for this control and have found that the `ToolBarOverFlowPanel` used internally is buggy. That's probably the source of your problem.

You can re-template the ToolBar and wire-up a different value for `WrapWidth` to try to fix the issue, but my guess is that you'll still run into layout problems.

Otherwise, you might consider making your own replacement control.

Comment: do you have an example of the replacement control?